# How to make a link the same width as an <li> horizontally

Tags: hyperlink, navbar

I have a navigation bar on the top of my page, and the links are laid out horizontally. Whenever I try to make the link the size of the whole li, it ends up putting all of the links on top of eachother. I tried to style the a tag to be display:block; with 100% width, but it messes up. Here is my code, can anyone help me?

```
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="top">   
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Hiscores</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    .container {width:100%;}
    #top {list-style:none;padding:5px;background:#E8E1A5;}
    #top a {text-decoration:none;color:#1D486F;margin:0px;width:100%;}
    #top .nav {display:inline;border-right:1px solid black;width:100px;padding:5px 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wYEJY/

You could try instead to set `width:100px` to `#top a`. But anchors are inline elements, so you have to set `display:inline-block`. Then, set `display:inline-block` to `#top .nav` too in order to minimize its width and have them horizontally.

So add the following code:

```
#top a {width:100px;display:inline-block;}
#top .nav {display:inline-block;}
```

You could also use

```
#top a {display:block;}
#top .nav {display:inline-block;width:100px;}
```

But this won't work on IE 7 because if you set `display:inline-block` to ablock element, it is rendered as a `block` element.

Another option: floating elements

```
#top{overflow:hidden;}
#top a {width:100px;display:block;}
#top .nav{float:left}
```

You can see all possibilities here: http://jsfiddle.net/wYEJY/1/

But remember that if you have an inline element, you can't add a `width` property to it; you should change it to `inline-block`.

And if you decide to use floating elements, remember to add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

after them, or set `overflow:hidden` (or something different than `visible`) to the wrapper which contains the floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I tried to put 6 links in the nag, dropped down to 5 links and it formatted fine. Don't know if this is an option but try it...